# 'str' object has no attribute

Tags: python, excel, attributeerror, strerror

I'm trying to open a column in excel and move all the values from it's cells into a list.

```
def open_excel(col, excel_file): 
   open_file = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file) 
   sheet_object = open_file.get_sheet_names()[0]
   cell_vals = []
   col_num = column_index_from_string(start_col)
   for cell in sheet_object.columns[col_num]: 
       cell_vals.append(str(cell.value))
```

After I run that I get the error:

```
builtins.AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

But I've already imported everything as well.

Here's what I've imported:

```
import openpyxl 
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter, column_index_from_string
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: Look at where `columns` is being accessed as an attribute.... `print(type(sheet_object))`.... look at where `sheet_object` was defined....Debugging complete.

Answer (score 2):

You have a *sheet name*, a string object, assigned to `sheet_object`:

```
sheet_object = open_file.get_sheet_names()[0]
```

`get_sheet_names()` returns a sequence of strings, not of objects; it just returns [`self.sheetnames`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html?highlight=get_sheet_names#openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook.sheetnames). You would have to use that name to get the actual sheet object:

```
sheet_name = open_file.get_sheet_names()[0]
sheet_object = open_file[sheet_name]  # subscription takes sheet names
```

You could more easily grab the first active work sheet with:

```
sheet_object = open_file.worksheets[0]
```